# Rcpp How to change a value directly inside a R List

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I know how to get values from a List objet, and how to create one within a C function.

But I would like to change a value in a List  which is given as a parameter
and that the modification would be effective when exiting the function.

Some thing like:

```
void myfunc(SEXP *lst) '
   List mylist (lst)
// make some modification

}
```

I need to modify a list within a recursive loop.

Thanks in advance
Daniel

Answer (score 4):

There is no magic. Just assign elements from a `List` object, and modify:

```
R> Rcpp::cppFunction("List foo(List L) { List L2 = L[0]; L2[1] = 42; return L2;} ")
R> L <- list(list(0,1,2), 2:4, 3.3)
R> foo(L)
[[1]]
[1] 0

[[2]]
[1] 42

[[3]]
[1] 2

R>
```

We pick the first element (and know it is a `List` itself; there are predicates for testing).  In that list, we set the second element.  You can do the same returning the *original but now modified* list:

```
R> Rcpp::cppFunction("List bar(List L) { List L2 = L[0]; L2[1] = 42; return L;} ")
R> L <- list(list(0,1,2), 2:4, 3.3)
R> bar(L)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 0

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 42

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 2


[[2]]
[1] 2 3 4

[[3]]
[1] 3.3

R>
```